# show ajax response as dropdown in new window

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, window.open

I have an auto-complete textbox where user can insert an actor name and it works fine. When user inserted the actor name, a dynamic dropdown should be populated containing list of movies by that actor, but not in the same page (I need to show this dropdown in a new window)

### Problem:

When user inserted an actor name, a new window is opened showing list of movies by that actor, but ***the problem is that these movies are not shown in dropdown.***

The second problem is that it opens more than one window (the number is not fixed, because I tried with different actor names and e.g once it opened 3 windows, another time 10 windows, ...)

I do appreciate if someone help me find what is the problem in my code and what should I change in it?

Here is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#tags").autocomplete({
           source: "actorsauto.php",
           minLength: 2,
           select: function (event, ui){
                  $("#tags").on('autocompletechange change', function (){
                    var selectedVal = $(this).val(); //this will be your selected value from autocomplete
               // Here goes your ajax call.      
                    $.post("actions.php", {q: selectedVal}, function (response){
                        var win= window.open("target.html","_blank","height=200,width=400, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
                        with(win.document)
                          {
                           open();
                           write(response);
                           close();
                          }
                       console.log(response);
                         $("#movieName").html(response).show();

                      });

                    }).change();
                 }
           }); 
 </script>

<html>
<body>
<input type="textbox" name= "tag" id="tags" style="display:none;" placeholder="Enter an actor/actress name here" />
<select id="movieName" name="movieName[]" multiple="multiple" width="200px" size="10px" style=display:none;>
<input type="button" value=">> Add to selected list >>" id="btnRight" style="display:none;" />
<select id="selectedItems" name="selectedItems[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:200px; size:10px;">
</select>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you use new window at all, it can be on same page?

Comment: @skobaljic: This is mainly because my professor asked me.. he didn't like the interface when I populated the dropdown in the same page.. because later we need to hide this dropdown and it caused some space problem in the page.. :|

Comment: when I say 'on same page' than I mean a popup-modal, an element with absolute position. 10 years ago you would open a new window, but nowadays you'd just raise a modal dialog.

Comment: @skobaljic: Tnx for explain it.. I am not so good with ajax and I didn't know it.. could you please guide me how to do it?

Comment: @skobaljic:I mean is it possible to populate dropdown in a new popup?

Comment: of course it is possible, for example look at `Popup with form` on [Magnific Popup plugin](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/).